# Занимаюсь парсингом номеров в facebook, так вот как спарсить все номера в определённой группе?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

Занимаюсь парсингом номеров в facebook, так вот как спарсить все номера в определённой группе?

В чём суть: в группе, к примеру, 12 тыс. человек, первоначально прогружено 50 человек, так вот, чтобы увидеть ещё 50, надо заскролить вниз, подождать, и тогда прогрузится.

Вопрос таков: как на selenium + python (Chrome) скролить страницу вниз , а также не получить бан (что, в принципе, беспокоит больше всего)?

Answer (score 1):

Существует несколько разных подходов к решению подобной задачи. Приведу пример одного из них, идея в следующем:

- находим либо футер, либо видимый элемент в футере
- в бесконечном цикле:

  - вызываем "scroll into view" на этот элемент
  - ждем пока количество элементов в желаемом списке увечичится (то есть как прогрузится очередная страница результатов)
- повторяем пока кол-во элементов до скролла инту вью и кол-во элементов после скролла инту вью не изменилось

Альтернативные или немного похожие примеры решения задачи:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32939911/771848
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/176458/24208
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888967/infinite-scroll-on-quora-using-selenium-in-python-and-javascript